# Massive fluxuation in nonpaged memory

Tags: windows-7, memory

Today I noticed that my system memory would periodically nearly max out, then return to normal, max out again, etc: [image: http://i.imgur.com/5hoIFcq.png]

Task manager shows nothing that accounts for that kind of usage, and there's nothing I have installed that should cause that kind of usage.

Looking at it in Poolmon: [image: http://i.imgur.com/4KuOIgA.png] there's something called "Tag3" that's apparently responsible for this, but I'm at a loss as to how I should fix it.  Nothing like this has happened before and "Tag3" is so generic that searching returns nothing of any use.

edit - I do actually have the Comodo Firewall installed, gonna uninstall and hopefully that fixes the issue.

Comment: If you want your accounts merged so you can properly track this question, http://superuser.com/contact and ask for a merge

Answer (score 0):

Open a cmd prompt and run the findstr command to see which driver uses this tag:

[image]

In your case TAG3

```
findstr /s TAG3 *.*
```

Now look at the file properties, find the driver version and look for an update. 1 Exmaple that I can find is [Comodo which uses this tag](http://comodorus.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3474).